# How to use tensorflow_io's IODataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, pcap, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to write a program that can uses malicious pcap files as datasets and predicts if other pcaps files have malicious packets in them.
After some digging through the Tensorflow doumentation,  I have found TensorIO, but I can't figure out how to use the dataset to create a model and predict with it.

Here's my code:

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras

try:
  import tensorflow_io as tfio
  import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
except:
  !pip install tensorflow-io
  !pip install tensorflow-datasets

import tensorflow_io as tfio
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

# print(tf.__version__)

dataset = tfio.IODataset.from_pcap("dataset.pcap")
print(dataset) # <PcapIODataset shapes: ((), ()), types: (tf.float64, tf.string)>
```

(Using Google Collab)

Iv'e tried looking for answers online, but couldn't find any.

Comment: Hi @Tomer Katzir, can you include a test .pcap file that can reproduce your error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have downloaded two pcap files and concatenated them. Later I have extracted the packet_timestamp and packet_data. Request you to preprocess the packet_data as per your requirement. If you have any labels to be added, you can add to the training dataset (In the below model example, I have created a dummy labels of all zero and adding as a column). If it is in a file then you can [zip](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#zip) them to pcap files. Passing a dataset of (feature, label) pairs is all that's needed for `Model.fit` and `Model.evaluate`:

**Below is an example of packet_data preprocessing -** May be you can modify like `if packet_data is valid then labels = valid else malicious`.

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_io as tfio 
import numpy as np

# Create an IODataset from a pcap file  
first_file = tfio.IODataset.from_pcap('/content/fuzz-2006-06-26-2594.pcap')
second_file = tfio.IODataset.from_pcap(['/content/fuzz-2006-08-27-19853.pcap'])

# Concatenate the Read Files
feature = first_file.concatenate(second_file)
# List for pcap 
packet_timestamp_list = []
packet_data_list = []

# some dummy labels
labels = []

packets_total = 0
for v in feature:
    (packet_timestamp, packet_data) = v
    packet_timestamp_list.append(packet_timestamp.numpy())
    packet_data_list.append(packet_data.numpy())
    labels.append(0)
    if packets_total == 0:
        assert np.isclose(
            packet_timestamp.numpy()[0], 1084443427.311224, rtol=1e-15
        )  # we know this is the correct value in the test pcap file
        assert (
            len(packet_data.numpy()[0]) == 62
        )  # we know this is the correct packet data buffer length in the test pcap file
    packets_total += 1
assert (
    packets_total == 43
)  # we know this is the correct number of packets in the test pcap file
```

**Below is example of using in Model -** The model won't work because I have not handled the packet_data which is of string type. Do the preprocessing as explained as per your requirement and use in the model.

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_io as tfio 
import numpy as np

# Create an IODataset from a pcap file  
first_file = tfio.IODataset.from_pcap('/content/fuzz-2006-06-26-2594.pcap')
second_file = tfio.IODataset.from_pcap(['/content/fuzz-2006-08-27-19853.pcap'])

# Concatenate the Read Files
feature = first_file.concatenate(second_file)

# List for pcap 
packet_timestamp = []
packet_data = []

# some dummy labels
labels = []

# add 0 as label. You can use your actual labels here
for v in feature:
  (timestamp, data) = v
  packet_timestamp.append(timestamp.numpy())
  packet_data.append(data.numpy())
  labels.append(0)

## Do the preprocessing of packet_data here

# Add labels to the training data
# Preprocess the packet_data to convert string to meaningful value and use here
train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(((packet_timestamp,packet_data), labels))
# Set the batch size
train_ds = train_ds.shuffle(5000).batch(32)

##### PROGRAM WILL RUN SUCCESSFULLY TILL HERE. TO USE IN THE MODEL DO THE PREPROCESSING OF PACKET DATA AS EXPLAINED ### 

# Have defined some simple model
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(100),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), 
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_ds, epochs=2)
```

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.

Comment: @Tomer Katzir - Hope we have answered your question. Can you please accept and upvote the answer if you are satisfied with the answer.

Comment: 1. How can I know which labels to add? 2. What do you mean by preprocessing of packet_data?